# Zend Tool cannot find php.exe

Tags: zend-framework

I am new to Zend Framework. I have placed my both bin and library folder in `C:\xampp\htdocs\Zend\`

In php.ini, I have given path `include_path = ".;C:\xampp\php\pear\;C:\xampp\htdocs\Zend\library"` and in environment variables, I have given path `C:\xampp\htdocs\Zend\bin;`

On writing command for creating project at the command prompt I receive an error

> "php.exe" is not recognised as internal or external command.

My command:-

```
c:\xampp\htdocs\Zend\bin> zf create project test
```

Answer (score 3):

Right click "my computer" go to "system properties" under "advanced" tab, click on "environment variables"
Under "system variables" find for the variable named "PATH" and click on "Edit" button
in "Variable Value" append the php.exe path with a semi-colon to the end of current string like below (without the inverted commas)

```
";c:\xampp\php\"
```

And then restart your command promt (so it can load new env variables you setup abv"

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you don't have the PHP5 CLI installed or it can't find it. The CLI is the command line interpreter which is a php version used to run commandline/cmd scripts like the zf.bat file uses.

Maybe xampp comes with a php.exe file, if so you could add it's directory to your system PATH too so php.exe can be found.

http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.commandline.php

Answer (score 1):

I guess your PATH environment should be like this

`c:\xampp\php\;C:\xampp\htdocs\Zend\bin`

the first path `c:\xampp\php\` will point to php.exe file location

the second path `C:\xampp\htdocs\Zend\bin` will point to zf.php location